# facebook javascript sdk login dialog blocked when invoked from flash

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I have a SWF file that calls some javascript which shows the facebook login dialog via the javascript sdk.

this all works fine, except for that fact that pop-up blockers block the login dialog, as it isnt invoked from a user action, but from flash.

any idea on how i could get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script....

http://snipplr.com/view/29544/

...but I doubt it will help much.

Or, What you could do is float a regular HTML button on top of your flash element so that it looks like it's part of the flash file and invoke the login procedure the old-fashioned way. This button could also be displayed/hidden/animated from flash to further integrate it into the user experience.